# How to refresh data in Entity Framework 4.1 code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following context:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Addresses.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Users.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I my application user may change data in say user data and then he may want to cancel changes. The best way to do this, is to refresh the `DataContext` from the database. But `DbContext` has no `Refresh` method. How can I refresh my `DataContext`?

Answer (score 3):

You can reload the entity from the database as follows.

```
context.Entry(user).Reload();
```

Or you can try out the methods described in [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c12bd8c8-231f-4dcc-a665-b048f7debbd7).